# Should a stringstream parse "INFINITY" as an infinite value?

Tags: c++, floating-point, infinity

Looking at the documentation for `strtod`:

Linux:

> An infinity is either "INF" or "INFINITY", disregarding case.

OS X:

> If the portion of the string following the optional plus
>   or minus sign begins with ``INFINITY'' ... it is
>   interpreted as an infinity

I'm using a `stringstream` to convert a `string` to a `double`, and (wrongly) assumed that `strtod` was being used behind the scenes. Neither clang++ 3.4 nor g++ 4.8 converts "INFINITY" to `inf`. Only clang++ seems to convert "INF" to `inf`.

Am I assuming too much about the operation of `stringstream`'s `operator>>`?  Or maybe I'm failing to check an important error condition? My test code is below (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra inf.cpp -o inf`).

### Test Code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

void
doTest(
    const std::string &str)
{
    double val1 = std::strtod(str.c_str(), nullptr);
    std::cout << str << " - std::isinf from strtod: " << std::boolalpha <<
        std::isinf(val1) << '\n';

    std::stringstream sstream(str);
    double val2;
    sstream >> val2;
    std::cout << str << " - std::isinf from stringstream: " <<
        std::boolalpha << std::isinf(val2) << '\n';

    std::cout << val1 << " vs " << val2 << '\n';

    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int
main()
{
    doTest("INFINITY");
    doTest("+INF");

    return (0);
}
```

#### Output

clang++ 3.4 (OS X 10.9.2):

```
INFINITY - std::isinf from strtod: true
INFINITY - std::isinf from stringstream: false
inf vs 0

+INF - std::isinf from strtod: true
+INF - std::isinf from stringstream: true
inf vs inf
```

g++ 4.8:

```
INFINITY - std::isinf from strtod: true
INFINITY - std::isinf from stringstream: false
inf vs 0

+INF - std::isinf from strtod: true
+INF - std::isinf from stringstream: false
inf vs 0
```

Comment: Looks like you found a bug in your Linux and MacOS standard C++ library. Congratulations! Is it `libstdc++`? Are you going to report it?

Comment: @Deduplicator http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19611

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went through the standard, and the stream operator should be defined in terms of the C function `strtod`, but only after filtering anything which could become Not-a-Number or infinity in Stage 2.

Following the document trail:

> #### 27.7.2.2.2 Arithmetic extractors
>
> As in the case of the inserters, these extractors depend on the locale’s num_get<> (22.4.2.1) object
>   to perform parsing the input stream data. These extractors behave as formatted input functions (as
>   described in 27.7.2.2.1). After a sentry object is constructed, the conversion occurs as if performed by
>   the following code fragment:

```
typedef num_get< charT,istreambuf_iterator<charT,traits> > numget;
iostate err = iostate::goodbit;
use_facet< numget >(loc).get(*this, 0, *this, err, val);
setstate(err);
```

> #### 22.4.2.1.2 num_get virtual functions
>
> Stage 2: If `in==end` then stage 2 terminates. Otherwise a charT is taken from in and local variables
>   are initialized as if by

```
char_type ct = *in;
char c = src[find(atoms, atoms + sizeof(src) - 1, ct) - atoms];
if (ct == use_facet<numpunct<charT> >(loc).decimal_point())
    c = ’.’;
bool discard = ct == use_facet<numpunct<charT> >(loc).thousands_sep()
  && use_facet<numpunct<charT> >(loc).grouping().length() != 0
```

> where the values src and atoms are defined as if by:

```
static const char src[] = "0123456789abcdefxABCDEFX+-";
char_type atoms[sizeof(src)];
use_facet<ctype<charT> >(loc).widen(src, src + sizeof(src), atoms);
```

> for this value of loc.

Comment: Great work tracking through the standard. I had started down this path myself shortly after posting. I did submit the bug (http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19611), but since several different libc++'s have this "incorrect," I'm still inclined to believe it's my fault. I'll keep things updated.